# Git commit keywords to interface TFS fields

Tags: git, tfs, commit, git-extensions

I use Git Extensions as interface to Git and keep the work tracked with Work Items in Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015.

A Git commit can be associated to a TFS Work Item using the syntax "#ID". What about other key words? Can anybody provide a list of them? 
I prefer answers that do work in the graphical UI of Git Extensions instead of having to handle a command line.

In my current case I needed something that makes text be shown in the "Comment" column of the "All Links" tab in Team Foundation Server. This would allow to differ between commits.

Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

There is not related  graphical user interface in GIT extensions to achieve this. You may have to use “#ID” where ID is the work item ID in console command, or using the UI features from the Pending Changes window in VS just as below picture:

[image]

There is no other key word of the commit message in the build in Git source control on TFS. However, with [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs), you can associate workitems in a commit message using [metadatas](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/doc/special-actions-in-commit-messages.md) (and even force commit policy!).

> - `git-tfs-work-item: <id>` will link the new changeset with the given    work item and the default action type.
> - `git-tfs-work-item: <id> <action>` will link the new changeset with    the given work item and the given action type.
> - `git-tfs-code-reviewer: <name>` sets the Code Reviewer field.
> - `git-tfs-security-reviewer: <name>` sets the Security Reviewer field.
> - `git-tfs-performance-reviewer: <name>` sets the Performance Reviewer    field.
> - `git-tfs-force: <reason>` will force the checkin, overriding TFS    checkin policies with the given reason.

Answer (score 0):

"#ID" is the only keyword you can use and there isn't any way to achieve the feature you want from Git Extension or command line. The only way to show some text in "Comment" is linking the commit to workitem from TFS Web Portal and enter the comment manually.

However this has been improved in [TFS 15](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/tfs15-relnotes). In TFS 2015, only the commit ID is shown in "All Links" tab. But from TFS 15, the commit comment will be also displayed as following when you check the "All Links":
[image]